# Is there a function or a combination of function that return the SE of the slope in Excel?

Tags: excel

**The Problem:**
I need to calculate only the slope's standard error.
I have a large data set and I need to calculate more than 1200 different Slope's SE values (and use them for further calculations).

I couldn't find a way only to calculate the slope's standard error.

**What I can do but prefer to avoid:**

I know that the function LINEST can calculate it using the Array formulas (CSE) that LINEST has. However I do not want to do and re-do over 1200 times it in order to extract just the one value (the Slope's SE) that I need.

**Data-set example:**

[image: Data example]

I need to calculate the slope standard error of yx1 (B1:F1,B2:F2), yx2 (B1:F1,B3:F3), yx3 (B1:F1,B4:F4), etc.

**Some ideas for solutions:**

If anyone can help or recommend a way to get only the slope's standard error value (of 2 variables series) it would be great and save me tons of time.

It can be a formula, a combinations of formulas or a way to use LINEST and extract only the Slope's standard error value.

Thanks!

Comment: Please consider reading [ask] and [edit] your question with a [mcve] of what your dataset looks like, what you've attempted, and what's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use INDEX with LINEST to pull one number.  Use Absolute and Relative References:

```
=INDEX(LINEST($B$1:$F$1,B2:F2,TRUE,TRUE),2,1)
```

Put that in G2 and copy down.  It will change the known x reference as it does so while keeping the known ys.

And the INDEX returns only the SE of the slope Row(2)Column(1) Number

[image]